# Как делить тип long long int с остатком на C?

Tags: c

```
counter[tmp] = ((tmpNumberCredit / pow(10, count - c - 1))) % 10;
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')
>   % не подходит под тип lon long int

Comment: `pow` функция как бы double возвращает. Сделайте явный каст.

Comment: Вы бы точно сказали, что именно хотите посчитать - потому что проблема не только в `pow`, но я еще и не уверен, что вам нужно именно целочисленное деление `tmpNumberCredit` на эту `pow`. Можно, леча в одном месте, перекалечить в другом.